# sms tm4b account balance request

Tags: php, api, sms

I'm using tm4b to send sms. Everything works fine with this code (https://www.tm4b.com/en/sms-api/)

```
$msgClient = \Tm4b\Rest\Client::create([
    'apiKey' => 'xxx'
]);

try {
    $response = $msgClient->messages()->send([
        [
            'destination_address' => '+33611111111',
            'source_address'      => 'TEST',
            'content'             => "Hello"
        ]
    ]);
    print_r($response);
} catch (\Tm4b\Exception\HttpClientException $e) {
    print_r($e->getResponseBody());
}
```

But how do you request the balance account ? I tried (not working). I should get the amount of credits I have left to send sms. Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Tm4b\Rest\Client::account() in

```
$responseAccount = $msgClient->account();
```

Comment: Instead of just saying _"not working"_, you need to explain what actually happens and what suppose to happen. The phrase "not working" can mean and be caused by many different things. Do you get the wrong result? Error messages? Server crashes? More info you give us, the better we can help.

Comment: Magnus : Sorry I made the corrections !

Comment: I'm guessing you are using https://github.com/tm4b/tm4b-php ? Helpful to add to the question too, with a link to the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the documentation of https://github.com/tm4b/tm4b-php (which I'm assuming you are using), it seems like you should be doing `$responseAccount = $msgClient->account()->describe();` instead of `$responseAccount = $msgClient->account();`

Comment: squall3d : Thanks but I still have with this syntax : Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Tm4b\Rest\Client::account() in ...

Comment: squall3d : Thanks that works ! TM4B toll me they made an API update this weekend !!!